# How toprint informations in footer

Tags: theme-development

Is there any filter or hook to print a script or add in the footer some content? I'm not talking about `wp_enqueue_` function, I'm creating a plugin that will show a banner for privacy and cookie info and I want to append it to the footer. I'm using at the moment this code, but I hope that there is a more clean wey to do it:

```
function cookie_privacy_script()
{
<script>
// js code here
</script>
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'cookie_privacy_script');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Printing content and adding a script to the footer are two different things.

If you want to add your banner html in the footer, you can use the `wp_footer` hook that will trigger when you call the `get_footer()` function from your theme.

You can simple echo your html (or load a template file).

```php
function myplugin_wp_footer () {
    echo '<div id="myplugin-cookie-banner">bla bla</div>';
    // or you can use include() function to load a PHP script instead
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'myplugin_wp_footer');
```

Then you can add your JS script as suggested by @CRavon

```php
function myplugin_cookie_privacy_script(){
  wp_enqueue_script( 'myplugin-cookie-script', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'js/cookie-banner.js', [], true, true);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'myplugin_cookie_privacy_script');
```

The last parameter of `wp_enqueue_script` tells that your script will be added in the HTML at the end of the body.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a cleaner way of loading script in footer  : use function [wp_enqueue_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) with the last argument `$in_footer` set to true. 
So your code will look like so :

```
function cookie_privacy_script(){
  wp_enqueue_script( 'your_script_name', path/to/your/script/on/server, '[dependencies, if, any]', true, true);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'cookie_privacy_script');
```

You will have to change "path/to/your/script/on/server" with the actual path of your script and '[dependencies, if, any]' by an array of dependencies of this script.